# Unity: Instantiate GameObject at top of screen plus it's own height

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code that instantiates GameObjects at the top of the screen and then they fall down.

```
float RandX = GetRandomXPos();
float RandY = screenSize.y;
Vector3 ballPos = new Vector3(RandX,RandY,0);
GameObject clone = Instantiate(BallPrefab, ballPos, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
```

This works fine but it spawn them *at* the top of the screen so they just blink into existence. I want to spawn them at the top of the screen plus the height of the prefab so that it can appear out of view and then fall down into view.

What is the best way to get that height that I need to offset by?

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the prefab you need to get the information of the Renderer that the prefab has.

To do this you have to get the component in its hierarchy, you can do this by using **GetComponentInChildren<*Renderer*>()**

Once you got the Renderer, you can access the bounds size with **renderer.bounds.size**

This is a **Vector3** which has the dimensions of the object, height being the **Y component**.

You may have more than one Renderer in a prefab so you will need to get them all with **GetComponentsInChildren<*Renderer*>()**. and calculate the sum of all the bounds using **bounds.Encapsulate**

```
var renderer = target.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();
var height = renderer.bounds.size.y;
```